# Puppet - Could not find environment 'none

Tags: puppet

We had seeing following errors for puppet-server and puppet-agent

```
Jun 22 19:26:30 node puppet-agent[12345]: Local environment: "production" doesn't match server specified environment "none", restarting agent run with environment "none"


Jun 22 19:44:55 node INFO  [puppet-server] Puppet Not Found: Could not find environment 'none
```

Configuration was verified couple of times and it looks fine. Production env exists.
Anyone has experienced similar issue?

We have enabled debug logging for puppet server however it doesn't seem point us to the root cause.

What part of code could be related to what we see here?
Regards

Answer (score 0):

The master is overriding the agent's requested environment with a different one, but the environment the master chooses is either empty or explicitly "none", and, either way, no such environment is actually known to it.  This is a problem with the [external node classifier](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/nodes_external.html#external-node-classifiers) the master is using.  Check the master's [`external_nodes`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/configuration.html#external_nodes) setting if you're uncertain what ENC is in play, or for a summary of Puppet's expectations for such a program.

If the ENC emits an `environment` attribute for the node in question, then the value of that attribute must be the name of an existing environment ('production', for example).  If you want to let the agent choose then the ENC should avoid emitting any `environment` attribute at all.

Comment: Thanks John for the explanation but not sure I understand why the master was overriding the request env with different none. The node terminus is set to plain (default setting), shouldn't  that force to use the main manifest. I am not a puppet expert so I might confuse terminology here.

Comment: @dies, data from an ENC is the only documented reason / mechanism for the master to override the agent's requested environment, which is why I assign responsibility for the problem there.  Or I guess there is the Puppet PE console, but surely you would have mentioned it if you were using PE, and anyway the same `node_terminus` setting you mentioned would be used to select that, too.  Note that it is primarily the configuration of the master that matters here, not that of the agents.